# Comic story early 80s with a giant blowing head

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title of a comic I read in my childhood.

#### Key plot points

1. The comic was set during the medieval era... maybe in the Middle East, Prince of Persia style? I don't recall exactly right now.
2. The main character was a classical hero. Smart, strong, an accomplished fighter, strong-willed, etc.
3. He had to complete several challenges and travel through different dangerous settings. I think that his ultimate goal was to rescue a woman (maybe a princess?).
4. The most remarkable fact I remember is him fighting a flying giant head which blew strong winds from his mouth.

Anyone recall something like it?

#### Chronology and Relevant Info

I read it in the early 80s. I remember the art being similar to the style of the classical Savage Sword of Conan issues, but in a more realistic style and in full color.

Comment: Actually kind of reminds me of [Zardoz](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070948/).

Comment: Which inspired the comic book character [Vartox](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Vartox_(Earth-One)) in the 70's and 80's. No idea if he ever flew a flying head in the comics though, and probably wasn't shown in a historic time period.

Answer (score 12):

The first thing that this reminds me of are the NES games [Wizards & Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_%26_Warriors) and [Ironsword: Wizards & Warriors II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironsword:_Wizards_%26_Warriors_II). Here's a screenshot of our hero, Kuros, fighting a giant head (made of clouds) which blows wind at him.

[image]

The rest of the setting matches as well. Kuros, when not wearing his armor, is depicted as a Conan-like warrior. In the first game, he travels through many different locations to rescue a princess. In the second game, he fights the evil wizard who has taken elemental forms, like the giant cloud head.

Here's the cover of Wizards and Warriors:

[image]

As well as Iron Sword:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't find any reference to a comic adaptation of this series. There was a novelization of the game, but it was text-only; there were no illustrations except the cover.

Comment: The head in the comic was a human head :(